# Neo4j apoc will not export

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I know there are hundreds of questions out there (and I have been looking prior to asking this!!) because whatever I try, Neo4j will not run the APOC export function.

`CALL apoc.export.graphml.all('/tmp/complete-graph.graphml', {useTypes:true, storeNodeIds:false})`

`Failed to invoke procedure` apoc.export.graphml.all`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Export to files not enabled, please set apoc.export.file.enabled=true in your neo4j.conf`

Here is the bottom of my neo4j.conf file:

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
dbms.directories.plugins=/var/lib/neo4j/plugins`
apoc.export.file.enabled=true
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
```

Here is the contents of `/var/lib/neo4j/plugins`:

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 neo4j adm 15949360 Apr 16  2020 apoc-3.5.0.11-all.jar`

I am running v 3.5 on Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the plugins was duplicated and also I needed the whitelist:

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=*
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
apoc.export.file.enabled=true
```

Along with this, I set `dbms.directories.import=/` which then allowed me to export along with creating the graph.xml file and setting permissions on it *before* neo4j could write to it.

If in doubt - pray about it! God always answers.

Answer (score 0):

This still didn't fix it.
Using Neo4j with DBMS 5.2

`//EXPORT til CYPHER CALL apoc.export.cypher.all("all-plain.cypher", {  format: "plain", useOptimizations: {type: "UNWIND_BATCH", unwindBatchSize: 20} }) YIELD file, batches, source, format, nodes, relationships, properties, time, rows, batchSize RETURN file`

gives same error:
[image]

and the neo4j.conf-file for this DBMS has this added:
[image]